# How can I save data when closing in Java

Tags: java

I make somekind video player. I want to save minut of users watching to database when closing the program. How can I do that? How can I write operations on exiting?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is using method `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(Thread hook)`. It will register a new virtual-machine shutdown hook where you can save data. When the JVM shuts down, the hook will be called and your code will be executed.

Here's a simple demo

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something
    }
}));
```

Comment: I don't use any thread and something like that, is there any other way?

Comment: Is there any problem in using thread? This is the only way to meet your needs as I know